# When is a static class initialized? Need to be called from the Application object when the app starts

Tags: java, android

I have extended the Application class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
  private static MyApplication instance;

  public MyApplication() 
  {
      instance = this;                      
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() 
  { 
     MyStaticClass.Start() // Here it crashes
     super.onCreate();       
  }

}
```

The problem that I'm having is I need to call a method from an static class as soon as the application starts. However it seems that static classes have not been initialized at this point so it crashes. Is there a way of doing that inside the application class? I don't want to do this from an activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's see what your static class looks like. Secondly, you can do whatever you want in your `application` class, but just move that static method call to AFTER the call to `super.onCreate()`. Thirdly, post the log!!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to redesign your app architecture. For instance, what do you mean under "as soon as the application starts"?

On Android the concept of "application start" is different from other platforms.

E.g. `Application.onCreate()` will not be called if your app's Java process was still alive by the time you pressed the app icon on the home screen. And vise versa - if your app process was killed by OS because your app was in background (e.g. due to an incoming call), then `Application.onCreate()` will be called while OS restores the app when call is finished. But from the user perspective this will not be an "application start".

Here is the documentation on this - [Processes and lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 1):

Static classes aren't initialized.  They aren't objects.  Static methods should use no state-dependent information, and static variables should not change.  They exist to provide functions and parameters to people using the class who don't need an instance of it.  They also allow you to do things which access private members of the class.

Realistically, classes aren't even static - they just have static members (methods and variables).

I would guess that the method start() isn't defined as static in MyStaticClass, meaning you have to instantiate a MyStatic Class instance first.

Static Classes essentially give you the opportunity to create SubClasses without creating sub Packages.  They work exactly like normal classes, but you have to call them via their MasterClass.

```
public class MyClass{
    public static class MyStaticClass{
        public MyStaticClass(){
            //Construct
        }
        public void MyMethod(){
            //Do stuff
        }
        public static void MyStaticMethod(){
            //Do Static Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Will result in the following properties:

```
MyClass C1 = new MyClass();                            //Totally Legal
MyClass.MyStaticClass C2 = new MyClass.MyStaticClass() //Also legal
MyClass.MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod()                 //Legal
C1.MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod()                      //Legal, but odd
C2.MyStaticMethod()                                    //Also legal, also odd
C2.MyMethod()                                          //Legal, intended use.

C1.MyStaticClass.MyMethod()                            //Unconditionally Illegal
MyClass.MyStaticClass.MyMethod()                       //Unconditionally Illegal
MyStaticClass.MyMethod()                               //Unconditionally Illegal
```